# _grokparsefailure on successful match

Tags: logstash, syslog, grok, logstash-grok

I started using logstash to manage syslog. In order to test it I am sending from a remote machine simple messges and try to parse them with logstash.

The only Logstash configuration, used via the command line:

```
input {
        syslog {
                type => syslog
                port => 5514
        }
}

filter {
        grok {
                match =>  { "message" => "hello %{WORD:who}" }
                }
      }

output {
        stdout { }
        elasticsearch {
                host => "elk.example.com"
                cluster => "security"
                protocol => "http"
        }
}
```

I do receive the logs and they are parsed correctly (a `who` field is generated). At the same time, `tags` contain `_grokparsefailure`.

The test log I am sending is `hello rambo3`. I see it as

```
2015-01-29T09:27:48.344+0000 10.242.136.232 <13>1 2015-01-29T10:27:48.113612+01:00 AA1.example.com testlog.txt - - - hello rambo3
```

The grok debugger also agrees:

[image]

Why is `_grokparsefailure` added to the tags?

Interestingly enough, the same data sent via pure `tcp` are parsed correctly by the same filter (`_grokparsefailure` is not in the tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_grokparsefailure` is not add by your own filter `grok`. When you use `syslog` input, the syslog format must be follow [RFC3164](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3164.txt), as mentioned in [here](http://www.logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/inputs/syslog).

Generally , `Syslog` input will parse the log and add corresponding `field` like `log severity`. So, there is a grok action in it. However, the log you send from remote server is in [RFC 5424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424) format. So, logstash can't parse the log and then add `_grokparsefailure` tag.